# Google AppEngine Datastore Dashboard: Create Entity with "legacy"-style ID?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I understand that the Google AppEngine Data Store changed their default policy on how ID's are auto-generated.

We have application code that expects all ID's to be less than the maximum value for an Integer.  In trying to create sample data using the dashboard ("Datastore Viewer"), there is a way to create Entities manually.  However when I do this, there appears to be no place to manually set the ID, and the auto-generated ID is larger than the maximum Integer value.

Setting `<auto-id-policy>legacy</auto-id-policy>` in appengine-web.xml and re-deploying did not seem to help.

I understand when you create Entities programmatically, you can specify your own ID number.  Is there any way to do this from the Dashboard, or at least use "legacy" auto-id generation?

Comment: Cool, I got the tumbleweed badge for this question. As far as I can tell, there is no way to do what I asked, I would answer this question myself except it would be a bit of a prove-no-solution-exists kind of situation.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Datastore Viewer only allows auto-generated IDs. :(